# Why is a line from html list missing? This keeps happening to me. "Wives" is missing

Tags: html, css

Why is a line from html list missing? This keeps happening to me. "Wives" is missing

Here is the code- I'm just trying to create. It's just a simple dropdown menu, but one of the dropdowns is not appearing...I'm being asked to add more details, but that's it!

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    font-family: arial;
}

ul li {
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 25%;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

ul li:hover {
    background-color: green;
}

ul li ul li {
    display: none;
}

ul li {
    position: relative;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        testy
    </title>
<charset-"UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" display="width=display-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

<ul>
    <li><a></a>Bowie</a></li>
    <li><a>Young</a></li>
    <li><a>Page</a></li>
    <li><a>Elvis</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>wives</a></li>
            <li><a>homes</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check it out..**

Don't hide `li` hide `ul` always

```css
body {

margin: 0;
border: 0;
background-color: blue;
font-family: arial;
}

ul li {
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 25%;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;


}
ul li:hover {
    background-color: green;
}


ul li ul {
    display: none;
}
ul li ul li {
    width:100%;
}

ul li {
    position: relative;
}

ul li:hover ul   {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top:100%;
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a>Bowie</a></li>
    <li><a>Young</a></li>
    <li><a>Page</a></li>
    <li><a>Elvis</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>wives</a></li>
            <li><a>homes</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It'd be good to explain what you changed and why it helps, rather than just dumping a pile of code.

Answer (score 0):

You've absolutely positioned the list elements, so they're all stacked on top of each other.

```
ul li:hover ul li   {
  position: absolute;
```

Comment: It all works much better now- responsive and neat. Thanks for everyone's help.